# My mouse doesn't show up when I play games!

Tags: technical-issues, mouse

When I play any kind of computer game my mouse doesn't show up. I can still click on things, I just have to spend forever searching the whole screen because I can't see it.
This is a recent problem, it used to work fine. This is a problem with the mouse pad, wireless mouse, and corded mouse (I've tried them all!).

Comment: Are you playing in windowed mode or full screen?

Comment: Unplug any usb.

Comment: @Brok3n the OP says this issue occurs with/without a wireless mouse, which needs a USB.

Comment: The OP may have a controller plugged in. Or the mouse is part of his keyboards drivers.

Comment: So the suggestion would be to unplug any *other* usb devices. In most games when a Controller or other kind of gamepad device is attached it will override the mouse/cursor.

Comment: this is a long shot, but it could also be the graphics drivers in some cases... we really need to have a list of games and fullscreen vs windows to help with more than generic answers though

Comment: Possuble duplicate of [Mouse Cursor Won't Display in Full Screen Games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51351/mouse-cursor-wont-display-in-full-screen-games)

Answer (score 1):

it can both be a software or hardware issue. if it were a software issue it might have some problem with usb drivers, try re-installing those, also try to check if you are not using any software that is interfering with mouse usb ports or such.

if it was a hardware issue, i would recommend you switch your mouse and see if it works, also try to create a new test user for your operating system and see if it solves the problem.

last solution will be try switching the usb ports.

Answer (score 1):

Answer originally posted by OP in comments:

> It was because I had the tail turned on on my mouse and the games wouldn't recognize it.

Answer (score -2):

It could possibly be a proplem with your display and the contrast. Try to reset your setting to default, or on a Mac you can enlarge the cursor size in system preferences + accessability (you probably can do this on a PC, but I just am not sure how).